# advantage of using dynamic type in c#

Tags: c#, .net

For example, if instance method `exampleMethod1`  has only one parameter, the compiler recognizes that the first call to the method, ec. `exampleMethod1(20, 4)`, is not valid because it contains two arguments.

The call causes a compiler error. The second call to the method, `dynamic_ec.exampleMethod1(10, 4)`, is not checked by the compiler because the type of `dynamic_ec` is dynamic. Therefore, no compiler error is reported.

So what is the difference between compile time checking and run time checking and advantage of using dynamic type?

Comment: Dynamic type is useful for *interoperability* with other languages like python,javascript .Without dynamic you have to rely on `reflection` to get the type of the object and to access its properties and methods.
With dynamic there's no need of reflection

Comment: It is worth noting that `var` will allow for compile time checking

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dynamic type is useful for interoperability with other languages or frameworks like python,javascript.

Without dynamic you have to rely on reflection to get the type of the object and to access its properties and methods. The syntax is sometimes hard to read and consequently the code is hard to maintain. Using dynamic here might be much easier and more convenient than reflection.

Anders Hejlsberg gave a great example at [PDC08](http://channel9.msdn.com/blogs/pdc2008/tl16) that looks like this:

```
object calc = GetCalculator();
Type calcType = calc.GetType();
object res = calcType.InvokeMember(
  "Add", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, 
  null, new object[] { 10, 20 });
int sum = Convert.ToInt32(res);
```

The function returns a calculator, but the system doesn’t know the exact type of this calculator object at compile time. The only thing the code relies on is that this object should have the Add method.

With the dynamic keyword, this code looks as simple as this one:

```
dynamic calc = GetCalculator();
int sum = calc.Add(10, 20);
```

---

[Reflection Vs Dynamic](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/593881/What-is-the-difference-between)

[Understanding the Dynamic Keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg598922.aspx)

Comment: You actually don't loose `Intellisence`. It is absent in both cases (`"Add"` is not going to be suggested, nor it will tell you how many parameters and what their types are).

Answer (score 0):

You should use dynamic only when you dont care about performance (the search for the right method is done by reflection api whi h is realy slow) and when you dont care to risk for a runtime error.
If you do want to use a dynamic call but dont want to risk your performance you can implement it youself using a cache from the argument types to the right method.
There is a method for finding the right method ill edit when i refind it.

Comment: If you have a method for runtime binding that is faster than using `dynamic`, I'd love to see it.

Comment: Iv'e implemented one a while ago. You need to create a class with a dictionary from a list of types to a MethodInfo and invoke the mwthod throught this class. The class should add to the dictionary the relevant method for the given type and invoke it if already exists. Worked super fast.

Comment: And how does it compare in speed to using `dynamic` in the same situation?

Comment: The first execution of a method is exacly the same as dynamic, any further calls are much faster (only dictionary search and regular execution)